# Quadratic formula not working?

Tags: quadratics

Suppose I want to find the $ n $ for which

$$(n)(n+1)/2 = 10 \Longrightarrow n^2 + n - 20 = 0$$

Clearly a solution is $4$. But, suppose we wanted to find that solution by use of quadratic formula. We get

$$4 = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1-80}}{2} $$

But that's clearly not true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $-4\cdot(-20)=80$

Comment: $-4ac=-4(1)(-20)=-(-80)=80$.

Comment: That should be $\dfrac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1+80}}{2}$

Comment: its $1^2-4\cdot1\cdot(-20)$=$1+80$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a positive
$$
\frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1\color{green}{+}80}}{2}
$$
Remember that the discriminant for $ax^2 +bx + c = 0$ is $b^2 -4ac$. Here $c = -20$. So $d = 1^2 - 4\cdot 1\cdot (-20) = 1 - (-80) = 1 + 80$.

Answer (score 3):

$$Ax^2+Bx+C=0\implies x=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$

$$\implies n=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot1\cdot(-20)}}{2\cdot1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1+80}}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is : $1 - 4(-20) = 81 = 9^2$ ! Not $-79$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$ be the discriminant.
Then we see that $\Delta = (1)^2 - 4 (1)(-20)$, so $\Delta = 1 + 80 = 81$.

$$(-1) \times (-1) = 1$$

Comment: Explaining your notation might be helpful :)

Comment: Delta? Never saw Delta as discriminant.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Always have myself (if a symbol is used at all, anyway).